# C - Read in file according to a format

Tags: c, file, scanf

I am trying to read a file in a specific file format in c.
the file contains some data items. every data item is seprated by a flag.
the file should look look like this:

```
file-header: "FIL0"
file-id: 0x1020304

flag : 0|1 : uint8_t
length : uint32_t
char[length] : int utf-8

so its: [File-Header] [FileID] [Flag | Length | Data ] [Flag | Length | Data] ...

--> "FIL0" | 0xFFFFFF | 0 or 1 | Data as char[] | 0 or 1 | ... (next data item) ....
```

My Problem occurs when reading in the file. My idea is to open the file and scan through it using some sscanf-magic.

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("data.dat". "r");
/* scan file for data components */

  while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, fp) != NULL) /* read in file */
    {
      /* scan for sequence */
      if (sscanf(buffer, "%5s", fil0_header) == 1) /* if the "FIL0" header is found */
        {
          printf("FIL0-header found: %s\n", buffer);

          // proceed and scan for [FLAG] [LENGTH] [DATA]
          // sscanf() 
          if (sscanf(buffer, "%u", node) == 1) 
            {
               // doesnt seem to work 
            }

          // read in length of string and extract stringdata

      else
        {
          printf("FIL0-Header not found, found instead: %s\n", buffer);
          // do something
        }
    }
```

My problem that I have a hard time with my buffer and the varying data types in the file.

The comparision of fil0-header works alright, but:

- how to read in the next hexadeciaml number  (sscanf using %D)

  how scan for the flag which is 1 byte

  how to extract the length which is 4 bytes

A problem is, that the check for the flag starts at the beginning of the buffer. 
but the pointer should be moved on, after the FIL0-header is found.
I'd be gratefull for any help!

Please help me to find the proper **sscanf()** -calls:

and want to read it in and retrieve the single parts of my file:
On single [File-Header] 
and many {[FileID] [Flag | Length | Data ]} {...} items

Comment: It does sound like it's a binary file ? And it does not seem to contain newlines.  Which'll make it hard to parse with fgets(), and if it is a binary format, you can't parse it with text handling functions.

Comment: no, its not binary. opening file with hexdum yields various formattings (Hex, String, Int)...

Comment: That doesn't mean much. binary files can have fragments of text in it. Can you open it in a text editor and make sense of it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you could just read the file per byte using

```
 line[0] = (char) fgetc(fp);
 line[1] = (char) fgetc(fp);
```

and so on or leave out the cast to retrieve an int-value... should do the trick to do an easy right to left scan of the file (or line - as you say there arent any line breaks)...

Comment: hey - thanks, thats exactely what I've been looking for. Actually, as a c noob - I thought, that this fgetc would read in a character... Oh well, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You probably could use some standard [parsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parser) techniques, for instance have a lexer and a recursive parser. You should define your input syntax more in details. You could perhaps use parser generators (but it might be overkill for your simple example) like ANTLR ...

I suggest you to read some good textbook on parsing (& compiling), it will learn you a lot of useful stuff.

Comment: thanks for the hint. But I already kind of apply a top down parsing: the question is to find the correspoding lexems.

Comment: Define precisely your lexical conventions, then implement them. You could read input line by line using `getline` if you find that helpful (but it might not be necessary in your case). Actually, I was not able to understand or guess the exact specification of your input file.